# How can I export my python web scrape data to a specific sheet in an existing excel file using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, request, css-selectors

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets. I would like to add new data from Python to a new sheet in the same Excel file using pandas. Is this possible to do without affecting my previous data? I am new... Thanks for any help!

Here is the Python code I am using so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import html
import cssselect

response = urlopen("https://www.xyz.com.shtml")
content = response.read()
tree = html.fromstring(content)

for div in tree.cssselect('.first_name'):
for a in div.cssselect('table:nth-child(2) a'):
    print(a.text)
```

I found this online... I am just a little confused how to use it in my current situation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to scrape a website and grab table element inside a class. I would suggest you to use BeautifulSoup instead.

Steps

1. grab your table inside class
2. append your data in a dictionary
3. convert to dataframe
4. export dataframe to excel

   ```
   from lxml import html
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests
   import pandas

   req = requests.get('https://www.xyz.com.shtml')
   soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

   content =  soup.find("table:nth-child(2) a", {"class": "first_name"})
   mydict = dict()
   for c in content:
     #from c append data in mydict
     # example: mydict['Data'].append(c.text)

   df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx')
   df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
   writer.save()
   ```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the code you commented out @AjayBisht? I am just trying to get the first name for now. Is it still necessary to append in this situation?

Comment: What i mean is.. grab the element of html you want to. If it is text then you will need to c.text. Whatever it is.. append it in the dictionary. Yes you will need to append the data in dictionary, which you will eventually save in excel sheet.

Comment: Beneath the line "for c in content:" I entered "mydict['Data'].append(c.text). I received the following error... for c in content: TypeError: 'NoneType' object not iterable. Any suggestions my friend? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case what it means is : content is empty. which could be because when you are scrapping the website, there could be a case where "table:nth-child(2) a" is empty or does not exist. You can do an "if content.isempty()" check before "for" loop or you can try grabbing the element through something other than "table"nth-child"